# Outgoing message with blue outline

Tags: macos, messages, monterey

In MacOS Messages, most outgoing messages have white text on a blue background (or green if it's SMS). But I have one conversation where one of the outgoing messages is blue text on a white background, with a blue outline around the message.

[image]

If I click on that message, the conversation is replaced with just that one message (which has reverted to the usual blue background) followed by one reply from my friend, similar to what happens when you right-click on a message and choose Reply.

Right-clicking on this message doesn't bring up the menu at all. And when I enable "Show Times", there's no timestamp next to this message.

Why is this message different?

Comment: Usually those are quotes, when the other party replies to one of your posts.  Is there not an identical message before (further up) that shows "1 Reply", or "X Replies" underneath?  You seem to have already identified this though.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see the previous one that this is a copy of. I guess it's when they reply to an earlier message. Post that as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone replies to one of your messages (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, or "Edit > Reply to Message...", or a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, or right click/tap on the message itself), the text they've replied to gets quoted in the format you've shown in your original post.

The message with blue background, you've found by clicking on this speech bubble with white background, is your original text. If you scroll backwards in the conversation you should also find this, your quoted text with "1 Reply", or "X Replies" underneath.

The newest operating systems also display the helpful "Reply" text underneath the actual quote itself:
https://support.apple.com/guide/messages/icht4a6d29fb/mac

Comment: I don't see the "Reply" heading, but maybe it only does that if there's a sub-thread with more than 1 message.

Comment: It should also show with only 1 reply.  I've got single replies like this, but e.g. my older Big Sur's Messages shows no "Reply" info underneath the quote.

Comment: Now I see it. It's under the original message (blue background), not the quote (clear background). That's tell me to look further down for the repeat with the reply.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, in older Operating Systems.  I just saw your tag "Monterey" (judging by the picture at the Apple Support site I'd linked to it should show there as well - strange) and Ventura are meant to also show it underneath the quote, which is an improvement.

Comment: I'm running Monterey with all updates (I put it in the tags).

Comment: @Barmar Yes, sorry I was a bit slow in noticing.  I don't have Monterey at hand to check, but so far Ventura shows it for a single reply too.

Comment: Could it be different for incoming and outgoing messages? The support page you linked to shows replies to an incoming message, mine was an outgoing message that my friend replied to.

Comment: The ones I'm looking at have them under in- and outgoing messages.  Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Curiously, on my iPhone, "1 reply" is under both the original and quoted message.